# How to open and select a file in Python

Tags: python, dialog

I want to open images in Python by selecting them in a dialog box, how can I do that? I tried tkinter and easygui but when I use them the program freezes and never loads. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of the code you tried? Where in that code does it freeze?

Comment: debug your code so it doesn't freeze

Comment: @SuperStew that sounds a lot like: "solve your problem so that you don't have it", it would be great tho if OP provided a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should provide a minimal reproducible example. Since you are a new member, I am giving you this example, which can be found here.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loading-images-in-tkinter-using-pil/

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog


def open_img():
    # Select the Imagename  from a folder
    x = openfilename()

    # opens the image
    img = Image.open(x)

    # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    # create a label
    panel = Label(root, image=img)

    # set the image as img
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(row=2)


def openfilename():
    # open file dialog box to select image
    # The dialogue box has a title "Open"
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='"pen')
    return filename


# Create a window
root = Tk()

# Set Title as Image Loader
root.title("Image Loader")

# Set the resolution of window
root.geometry("550x300+300+150")

# Allow Window to be resizable
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

# Create a button and place it into the window using grid layout
btn = Button(root, text='open image', command=open_img).grid(row=1, columnspan=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ok I managed to solve it with the functions! thanks!!